# Create a fileset from a comma-separated list in a property without losing order

Tags: ant, fileset

I use a specified property to create fileset:

```
<property name="cases" value="B.java,A.java,C.java" />
<fileset id="casesToBeRunning" dir="${src}" includes="${cases}" />
```

When casesToBeRunning created, I list the content of it:

```
<echo>Cases to be running: ${toString:casesToBeRunning}</echo>
```

it shows A.java,B.java,C.java which I'm not expected to.

I don't want Ant autosort for me, I need the original sort order of the property I defined to execute the cases orderly.

Anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ant filesets don't retain order - as you've seen.  The related [`filelist`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filelist.html) type does respect ordering, so you might use:

```
<filelist id="casesToBeRunning" dir="${src}" files="${cases}" />
```

Whether the order is respected will depend on what task you plan to use to process the files.  Most core Ant tasks that accept a fileset will accept a filelist instead, so you should be ok with them.  For non-core tasks it may not work.

*(Note that before Ant 1.8.0 some tasks didn't respect the order when traversing a filelist - among them `copy` for example).*